# Cannot make shell file excecutable

Tags: command-line, permissions

read-only file system error when trying to make shell file excecutable. FIX?

Comment: Your file system is mounted read-only, you have to mount it read-write. Until you update your question with more info (What kind of device it is? How is it mounted? What fs does it use? Did you do something to make it mount read-only?) we can't give more advice.

Comment: In other words, please post the results of the `mount` command and the full path of the script.

Comment: It just gives an error that filesystem is read only

Answer (score 2):

As @falconer says, you can **mount the device read-write** to `sudo chmod u+x file` successfully. This may not be feasible if you don't have access rights or the file system driver doesn't support mounting it writeable.

You could also **copy** the file to a device which is ***already* mounted read-write** (`/tmp` comes to mind) and run it from there. Of course this might not work if the script somehow depends on which directory it's run from (which scripts generally should *not*).

Comment: I am running the os in VMware Workstation.